# Defect measure associated to a sequence of exponentials

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure, pseudo-differential-operators, microlocal-analysis

In my road to understand microlocal defect measures, at the beginning of Gerard's article [Microlocal defect measures](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03605309108820822), there is an statement about (an example of) defect measures where I am struggling.

The context is the following. Let $\Omega$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and let $(u_n)_n$ be a bounded sequence in $L_{loc}^2(\Omega)$ which converges to $u\in L_{loc}^2(\Omega)$ in the sense of the distributions. By identifying $L^1$ with a subspace of the space of Radon measures, a weak-$*$ argument allows us to deduce that
$$|u_n-u|^2\rightharpoonup \nu$$
where $\nu$ is a Radon measure, called the **defect measure** associated to $(u_n)_n$.

To exemplify that the defect measures does not capture some important properties, the sequence $u_n(x)=\exp(inx\cdot \xi)$, for some $\xi\in \mathbb{R}^d\setminus\{0\}$, is examined. This sequence is bounded in $L_{loc}^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$, $u_n\rightharpoonup 0$ in the sense of the distributions and does not converge strongly in $L_{loc}^2$. The defect measure $\nu$ associated to this sequence is the Lebesgue measure, for any $\xi\in \mathbb{R}^d$.

**My question is:** how do I find that, indeed $\nu=\lambda$? I've been thinking about it, but I did not be able to unravel the statement. Any hint is well received!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that $\lambda$ in your notation stands for $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, we can observe simply that the sequence of interest to you is
$$
|u_n(x)-u(x)|^2=|\exp(inx\cdot\xi)|^2=1,
$$
which then *is* the Lebesgue measure. If it is not clear why this is, simply write the definition of $|u_n|^2\rightharpoonup \lambda $.

Comment: I forgot that I did ask this. Yes, I was able to solve my doubts back then :) I will check your answer as correct.